# Finding in outer collection, adding from inner collection

Tags: java, collections, for-loop

I would like to ask for help.

1. I have Objects.
2. Objects have Collection of "rooms" and "people".
3. I need add every "people" to extra List from selected "building"

Code is clearer:

```
    public void findPeopleInRoom(String selectedWord) {

    List <String> listPeople= new ArrayList<>();

    //school.subordinateBuildings() return List of buildings
    //b.people() return List of people

        for(IBuilding b: school.subordinateBuildings()) { 
            if(b.getName().equals(selectedWord)) {
                for(Person p1: b.people() ) {
                    listPeople.add(p1.getName());
                }
            }
            else {
                for(IBuilding b2: b.subordinateBuildings()) {
                    if(b2.getName().equals(selectedWord)) {
                        for(Person p2: b2.people() ) {
                            listPeople.add(p2.getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(listPeople);
            return;
        }
    }
```

EXAMPLE(Structure):

- School("name")(every object has List of people and List of buildings):

  - "A"
  - **"B"**

    - "B1"
    - **"B2" -> List of People**
  - "C"

But thats up doesnt work very well for me, a little bit randomly. Most times will not print anything, sometimes right.

Thanks to everybody.

MmM ...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the given piece of code semantically, but I couldn't get your example structure. If there is an issue with printing, then probably you should override the toString() method.

Comment: one thing that seems to be so weird - your SOP and return statements are within the for loop...any specific reasons of not using them outside the loop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return;` statement is within the for-loop. So it will execute after the 1st iteration, and exit the method. To run your loop over all buildings get rid of the `return;` statement, you don't need it in `void` methods anyway.

Comment: Right. Now I get it, next stupid mistake. Sorry. Very thanks.